# From where the light comes?

Tags: light, supermassive-black-hole

Gravitational field of a supermassive blackhole is so strong that even light cannot escape from it (eg. black hole in the core of M87). In this case when a blackhole tears a star,a bright disk of accelerating gas makes easier for us to spot blackholes. but the question is, if black holes pulls all the EM rays into it, how we can see the light from the disk ?. How X-rays are detected if it pulls all the EM rays into it ?.

Comment: th;dr  The accelerating gas in the accretion disk giving off X-rays is outside the black hole, not inside.

Comment: @JamesK you mean outside event horizon ?

Comment: Yes, outside the event horizon.